# Calculate minimum IV increase to offset theta

Tags: options, implied-volatility

How would one calculate the minimum implied volatility increase necessary to offset theta decay?

IV is typically a percentage, while theta is a dollar value.

In theory I think I could look at what the theta is, add (instead of subtract) that value to the current theoretical option price and find out what the IV of that new option value would be

but I was wondering if others had a way to get this same information